# How do I forward `<Ctrl>-<Tab>` in Konsole?

Tags: c++, emacs, tabs, ubuntu, konsole

I want to use intelligent tabbing in Emacs in C++ mode, but I also want to be able to insert a tab character when necessary.  From other posts, I gather that the easiest way is to bind `<Ctrl>-<Tab>` to indent.  However, it appears that Konsole in KUbuntu won't forward the `<Ctrl>`?

My current .emacs file contains:

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()  
 (setq c++-tab-always-indent t)
 (setq tab-width 4)
 (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
 )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)

(global-set-key [C-tab] 'self-insert-command)
```

So I believe that this will bind `<Ctrl>-<Tab>` to inserting a tab character.  However, when I run:

`<Ctrl>-h k <Ctrl>-<Tab>`

Emacs only reports that I pressed the tab key.  Is there some option to Konsole (which I have searched through to no avail) or global preferences in KUbuntu that I need to set so that the `<Ctrl>-` is also forwarded?  (It certainly forwards all of the other `<Ctrl>-blah` commands.)

Comment: Well, it seems that konsole itself treats ctrl-tab as tab (on my box at least). ctrl-tab tab completes exactly like tab does when typing at the command line. It looks like konsole does not recognize ctrl-tab as being different from tab.

Comment: I tested Konsole, Gnome Terminal, and xterm. Only emacs running in xterm could distinguish TAB from C-TAB

Comment: Then it would seem C-TAB is just a silly idea.  Which key combination should I bind to?  Or does this ability, to add a Tab character, [without disabling the intelligent tabbing], already exist and I simply don't know the correct key combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Control-Q (quote, is what I think of in order to remember this), and then press your Tab key, and you'll insert a tab character.  You can use Control-Q to insert any character sequence you need to.  Hope this helps.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve the same problem and I found the answer here:
http://www.linux-archive.org/ubuntu-user/189410-equivalent-xterm-vt100-translations-string-gnome-terminal.html

What I did is the followings.

1. prepare my own konsole key bind customization file
   ~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/linux-custom.keytab
2. run konsole by specifying the keytab I customized

   % konsole --keytab linux-custom
3. bind keys in Emacs

My binding in linux-custom.keytab is

```
key Tab   +Control       : "\E[4t" # control tab will generate esc [ 4 t
key Backtab              : "\E[4s" # shift tab will generate esc [ 4 s
```

(I don't know any rule for assigning key code so I chose some code which are not yet used.)

In my Emacs customization file called from .emacs I put the following bindings

```
(define-prefix-command 'terminal-key-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "\e[") 'terminal-key-map)
(define-key terminal-key-map (kbd "4t") 'other-window) ;control tab
(define-key terminal-key-map (kbd "4s") 'other-window) ;shift tab
```

I also customized other keys such as `control ;`, `control '`, `control =`, etc. in the same way.